# Mono does not appear to be installed error (WineTricks)

Tags: wine, mono

I'm trying to install dotnet4.5 using winetricks on Ubuntu12.04 64bit. It keeps on giving me "Mono does not appear to be installed " error though i have mono installed . I ran these two commands to get mono and mono-complete

```
sudo apt-get install mono

sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

wine version i am using is Wine 1.6. I have already Tried reinstalling wine . Its not just dotnet4.5 but all the versions of dotnet give me the same error .

Answer (score 6):

http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono

d/l the latest version and place the .msi into /usr/share/wine/mono

then continue with installation of dotnet45

Answer (score 5):

Do the below to install `wine-mono`.

1. Download [wine-mono.msi](http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono) from the official winehq site.
2. Type `wine64 uninstaller`.
3. Press <kbd>install</kbd> from the uninstaller GUI and select the downloaded `.msi` package.
4. Done!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you don't need Mono. The [WineHQ wiki page for Mono](https://wiki.winehq.org/Mono) says:

> The Mono package should always be removed before installing native
>   .NET. This can be done with the following command-line:
>
> ```
> $ wine uninstaller --remove '{E45D8920-A758-4088-B6C6-31DBB276992E}'
> ```

That page also explains the installation of Mono for Wine.